# Xpath for Text of <p> tag until Following-sibling::h2[text()='some text']

Tags: xpath

I want xpath for all text of `<p>` tag following by first h2 until Next h2

Xpath should be like `//h2[text()='Title 1']/following::p`  with condition

```
----other code-----
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<p>Title 1 text</p>
<p>Title 1 text</p>
<h2>Title 2</h2>
<p>Title 2 text</p>
<p>Title 2 text</p>
----other code-----
```

I expect the result as Title 1 text, but actual output is Title 1 text and Title 2 text

**Note**: count of the `<p>` tag is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using xpath 2.0, use this.

```
   distinct-values(//p[following-sibling::h2[text()='Title 2'] or preceding-sibling::h2[text()='Title 1']]/text())
```